# Google Android and Eclipse with ADT: Moving installed component from one pc to another

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I am beginner in Android. I have downloaded the Android 2.3 windows installer and installed it on a PC. Next I have run the SDK Download Manager and installed all the components. I have run the main installer on another pc, and basic android 2.3 is installed there. Now I want to move the downloaded components to the second PC so that I won't have to download it twice. Will it work?

Also I have downloaded ADT plugin for eclipse into the first PC. Now I want to move the entire eclipse folder to the second PC. Will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have installed a plugin in eclipse then it will be copied under eclipse extracted directory. So, you can safely move the eclipse extracted directory to another PC and this will migrate all your plugin also.

Installing Android SDK on Windows means extracting the android-sdk-windows to a directory. This is also portable. Move this also to another PC and that should work seemlessly.

May be you will have to set the Android SDK path again in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Should not be a problem, make sure to copy the Android SDK folder as well as the eclipse folder and run the SDK Update tool from within eclipse afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It works fine. For this u have to move your eclipse and Android SDK folder to your PC.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to copy .android folder from C:/user/your_name